# How to find element in GWT applilcation when no unique locator is given?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gwt

```
<div class="LIJLHMB-ab-b-com-sencha-gxt-theme-neptune-client-base-field-Css3FieldLabelAppearance-Css3FieldLabelStyles-fieldElement" style="padding-left: 125px;">
   <div id="x-auto-93" class="LIJLHMB-M-e-com-sencha-gxt-theme-neptune-client-base-field-Css3TextFieldAppearance-Css3TextFieldStyle-focus" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus="true" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingblur="true" style="width: 275px; height: 32px;">
      <div class="LIJLHMB-M-i-com-sencha-gxt-theme-neptune-client-base-field-Css3TextFieldAppearance-Css3TextFieldStyle-wrap" style="width: 275px;">
         <input id="x-auto-93-input" class="LIJLHMB-M-h-com-sencha-gxt-theme-neptune-client-base-field-Css3TextFieldAppearance-Css3TextFieldStyle-text LIJLHMB-M-c-com-sencha-gxt-theme-neptune-client-base-field-Css3TextFieldAppearance-Css3TextFieldStyle-field" type="text" style="width: 275px;" value="" tabindex="0"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="LIJLHMB-ab-a-com-sencha-gxt-theme-neptune-client-base-field-Css3FieldLabelAppearance-Css3FieldLabelStyles-clearLeft"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Above is my code. The id and class which are given is auto id/class and changes every time new build installed. So in such case how to find input element from DOM while doing automation? Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

With the [@external](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#External_and_legacy_scopes) annotation you can force some CSS classes/ids to be excluded from obfuscation, so they are usable by selenium tests:

> ```
> @external legacySelectorA, legacySelectorB;
> .obfuscated .legacySelectorA { .... }
> .obfuscated .legacySelectorB { .... }
> ```
>
> In the above example, the .obfuscated class selector will be
>   obfuscated, and the obfuscated() method will return the replaced name.
>   Neither of the legacy selectors will be obfuscated and the
>   legacySelectorA() method will return the unobfuscated value.
>   Furthermore, because the legacySelectorB is explicitly defined in the
>   @external declaration, the inaccessible class name will not trigger an
>   error.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your are trying to test an application based on GXT 4.

Your problem is, that the class names will be obfuscated and the id are generic. So both can not be used for testing.

To make your application testable, add the following line to your module descriptor:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug"/>
```

And call ensureDebugId(Element el) for every widget you want to test:

```
myWidget.ensureDebugId(myWidget.getElement(), "myDebugIdValue");
```